# Chamar uma variável a partir de outras no LESS

Tags: variáveis, less

Como posso chamar uma variável a partir de outras variáveis como em outras linguagens no less?

**PHP:**

```
$name = 'stack';
$level = '900';

$nameVariable = $name . $level;

${$nameVariable}; // chama variável: $stack900
$$nameVariable; // chamar variável: $stack900
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, depois de tentar bastante consegui!!!

**Less:**

```
@name: stack;
@level: 900;

@nameVariable: ~'@{name}@{level}';

@@nameVariable; // chama variável: @stack900
```

O porquê de se utilizar `@{name}@{level}` ao invés de `@name@level` é:

**Exemplo:**

```
@{name}@{level} // stack900

@name@level // stack 900
```

e o `~`é para remover as aspas ' '